# Split report parameters in stored procedure

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I work with CRM 2015.
When I try create report with multiply-values parameter, I can not split it on list id.
I tried many ways to do it like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pn_rep_LoadResources]
    (@Stage NVARCHAR(1000))

WHERE(stage.new_stageid IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Stage,',')))
WHERE(stage.new_stageid IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(@Stage,',')))
WHERE(stage.new_stageid IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(@Stage,',')))
WHERE(stage.fn_GetGuidsFromString IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(@Stage)))
```

And other, but nothing works.
Have anyone problem like this?

Comment: If your parameter is set to `Allow multiples Values` you don't need to explicitely split it in the dataset. Just `Where column in (@my_param)` it should work. Be sure `@my_param` is mapped to SSRS parameter in the dataset properties / parameters tab

Comment: If I use Where column in (@my_param) used only first value from multivalue parameters. Not all.

Comment: I do it in stored procedure

Comment: Just FYI creation of stored procedures/functions is not supported for Microsoft Dynamics CRM. But if you want to use it anyway you will have to provide an access to procedures/functions to Network Service account (or other account that is used for Reporting Services service).